# Request Google Maps Update from Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android app that interacts a lot with Google Maps, and, if the Google Maps app is not updated, it loses some functionalities. Do you know any elegant way of requesting the users from my app to update the Google Maps app?

Cheers,

Mauricio Güell

Answer (score 1):

Before using app functionality in your app..write a code to check the version of the app directly from playstore.

Later match whether the users map version  and the version one in the store matches ...if matches then use map functionality in app or else popup message saying "update your map to continue" and redirect user to google playstore.